# How to reference a combination of dict() and list() in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

This is an example of a complexe data structure. The depth of the structure is not fixed. To reference a specific datum in the structure I need a unknown number of indices (for `list()`) and keys (for `dict()`).

```
>>> x = [{'child': [{'text': 'ass'}, {'group': 'wef'}]}]
>>> x[0]['child'][0]['text']
'ass'
```

Now I want to have single keys for the values like this.

```
keys = {'ID01': [0]['child'][0]['text'],
        'ID02': [1]['group']}
```

But this is not possible. Is there another pythonic way?

Comment: `[0]['child'][0]['text']` on its own doesn't mean anything without a name on which it acts on. Assign something to `x[0]['child']`, e.g `sub = x[0]['child']` and then grab `sub[0]['text']` and `sub[1]['group']` (if this is what you're asking)

Comment: Do not confuse actual complexity for a lack of clear understanding. If you really understand your own problem, you should be able to explain it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a couple of things here.  First is a custom lookup function:

```
def lookup(obj, keys):
    for k in keys:
        obj = obj[k]
    return obj
```

Then a dictionary of keys to key list tuples:

```
keys = {'ID01': (0,'child',0,'text'),
        'ID02': (1,'group')}
```

then you can do this:

```
lookup(x, keys['ID01']) # returns 'ass'
```